# aggregate values based on categories

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate, categories

I have a DataFrame like:

```
SK_ID_CURR  CREDIT_ACTIVE   CREDIT_DAY_OVERDUE

436084         Sold               0

436084         Active            951

436084         Sold               0

436084         Active             0

436084         Bad debt           0

436084         Active            936

436084         Active            951
```

I'd like to make new columns for each CREDIT_ACTIVE category, with the corresponding sum of values of CREDIT_DAY_OVERDUE.

The result should look like:

```
SK_ID_CURR  CREDIT_ACTIVE_OD  CREDIT_BAD_DEBT_OD CREDIT_ACTIVE_SOLD_OD

436084       2838                 0                 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and aggregate `sum`, last reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = (df.groupby(['SK_ID_CURR','CREDIT_ACTIVE'])['CREDIT_DAY_OVERDUE']
        .sum()
        .unstack(fill_value=0))
```

Or use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
df = df.pivot_table(index='SK_ID_CURR',
                    columns='CREDIT_ACTIVE',
                    values='CREDIT_DAY_OVERDUE',
                    aggfunc='sum',
                    fill_value=0)
```

Then change columns names:

```
df.columns = ['CREDIT_{}_OD'.format(x.upper()) for x in df.columns]
```

And last create column from index:

```
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
   SK_ID_CURR  CREDIT_ACTIVE_OD  CREDIT_BAD DEBT_OD  CREDIT_SOLD_OD
0      436084              2838                   0               0
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`pd.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
res = pd.pivot_table(df, index='SK_ID_CURR', columns='CREDIT_ACTIVE',
                     values='CREDIT_DAY_OVERDUE', aggfunc='sum')

print(res)

CREDIT_ACTIVE  Active  BadDebt  Sold
SK_ID_CURR                          
436084           2838        0     0
```